# Can I sign my WPF clickonce manifest after distribute the application

Tags: wpf, certificate, clickonce, codesign

I already roll out my application without tick "Sign the clickonce manifests". But when my client install the application always been block by smartscreen of anti virus, so end up I decided to get a EV code sign, but not sure will have any impact to my client on next release that after I enable the sign mannifests. Do my client need to reinstall the application? Or can update without issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will most likely need to re-install. I spent some time trying to do the same thing and in the long run it was easier to have them re-install. The EV certificate may not make a difference right away but it helped me in the long run.